# can't get @mui 5 styled components to work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I'm following the tutorial on [mui's website](https://mui.com/getting-started/installation/) to get the version 5 of the framework in place. Everything is fine except that I cannot figure out how to make the styled components work.

Here is a minimal example [with a sandbox to try it out](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-co6cv?file=/index.tsx:0-817):

```js
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { createTheme, styled, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#4cfcb3",
      light: "#8affe5",
      dark: "#00c883",
      contrastText: "#000"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#00b0ff",
      light: "#69e2ff",
      dark: "#0081cb",
      contrastText: "#FFF"
    }
  }
});

const Test = styled(() => <div>TEST SHOULD BE RED</div>)({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "#000"
});

const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
      Hello Button
    </Button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <Test />
  </ThemeProvider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

In this example, we can see that the button correctly gets the colors as specified in the theme, so that.s good, but my `Test` styled component isn't styled at all as you can see here:

[image: visual output of code example]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace this code to make it work

```
const Test = styled("div")(() => ({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "#000"
}));
```

and inside your App component you can you use it with that form
`<Test>This is red </Test>`

**Explanation**

If you want to styled a html element like `<div>` or `<p>` you need to do wrap it with `""`.

`const StyledDiv = styled("div")(() => ({ some attributes }))`

or if you want to style a Material UI component (for example  then you can use it like this

`const StyledButton = styled(Button)(() => ({ some attributes }))`

Answer (score 2):

You have to call it like [this](https://mui.com/pt/system/styled/):

Basically you have to remove your callback and only pass it the `'div'`, and a config object with the CSS properties.

To call it use the opening and closing tag of the component.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import { createTheme, styled, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

import { Button } from "@mui/material";

const theme = createTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: "#4cfcb3",
      light: "#8affe5",
      dark: "#00c883",
      contrastText: "#000"
    },
    secondary: {
      main: "#00b0ff",
      light: "#69e2ff",
      dark: "#0081cb",
      contrastText: "#FFF"
    }
  }
});

const Test = styled('div')({
  color: "red",
  backgroundColor: "#000"
});




const App = () => (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <Button color="primary" variant="contained">
      Hello Button
    </Button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <Test>TEST SHOULD BE RED</Test>
  </ThemeProvider>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm sorry I accepted the other answer because it provided a bit more info, but that was a tough decision :)

Comment: @djfm glad to have helped you. and I added some info here